No `double` trouble, but `decimal` trouble
Lately I have been playing with data types double and decimal in C# once more. As I understood, decimal should be used in cases where decimal rounding errors should be avoided, like in financial calculations.
So I was looking for a demo example for showing that decimal is actually better than double when it comes to rounding errors. I came up with this calculation: divide 1 by 3 and multiply that result with 4.5. The end result should be 1.5.
So I executed the following C# code in a console application so that I could compare decimal and double:
Console.WriteLine($"Double result: {1.0 / 3.0 * 4.5}");
Console.WriteLine($"Decimal result: {1m / 3m * 4.5m}");

The output struck me hard!:
Double result: 1.5
Decimal result: 1.4999999999999999999999999998

When rounding to integer values, the double result is rounded to 2, but the decimal result is rounded to 1...
Why is using the decimal type incorrect here?

1.0 / 3.0 cannot be properly represented in a decimal way (base 10).

The double result is incorrect.

@HansPassant no, it's correct: fiddle.

Don't think of decimal as the universal replacement for double. Both have different constraint when they should be used or not. If you have somewhat control over the range of decimal places your system needs to work within choose decimal. If not like here use double or rearrange your math expressions in a way that you stay within the  limits of decimal places of the decimal type and then use decimal.

decimal preserves the decimal representation of the number up to a certain precision. In this case to output the decimal number correctly it was required to explicitely asks how many digits of precision you wanted to round the number toMath.Round(result, 2) => 1.5

The rounding comment, while disconcerting at first glance, is a bit of a red herring. You are performing calculations whose exact result is on the rounding "boundary". Any floating point or decimal calculations could introduce tiny rounding errors, so you can never guarantee which "side" of the boundary the calculated result will fall. To round safely, you could round twice: once to remove tiny rounding errors (leaving you with 1.5 exactly) and then again to round to the nearest integer. This will ensure that anything sufficiently close to the boundary rounds in the same direction.

On a current framework you might want to take a look at (1m/3m).Scale how many decimal places it will have. You will see that it can't be accurate.

Both decimal and float are floating points, although one uses 128 bits, the other 64. The real rounding error occurs at 1/3 and is only visible if you display 28 digits or more. Otherwise both numbers appear as 1.5. At 28 digits, 1.0/3.0 is 0.3333333333333333148296162562 while 1m/3m is 0.3333333333333333333333333333

Long story short, decimal is correct, not double. Or rather, decimal has a smaller error than double.

@Ralf: Thanks for the tip regarding correct choice of data types based on the situation at hand. Generally, I am actually pretty reluctant to use decimal. Most of my regular use cases justify using double instead of decimal.

@NeilT (and @Ralf): I understand the tip for performing a rounding in two steps. However, I tend to be very careful with that, since in other situations it might actually increase the rounding error. For example, I generally do not want to round 1.45 to 1.5 and then 1.5 to 2.

@PanagiotisKanavos: Thank you very much for this elaboration. Very insightful. I assume that the given representation of 1.0/3.0 occurs because of a conversion of a double value to a decimal value, right? Up to the accuracy of the 64-bit double type, the decimals are all 3's. I assume that a quadruple floating point number would actually include more 3's behind the decimal sign.

@BartHofland - re "I generally do not want to round 1.45 to 1.5 and then 1.5 to 2", the way to address this is to perform your first rounding at a high level of precision, e.g. to 10dp or similar. Then 1.49999999999874 and 1.500000000000295 will both round to 1.5000000000. Then you can round safely to 2dp (or whatever is required), so that both become 1.50 (while 1.4500.... will become 1.45). Of course, even the first rounding will have its own boundaries, and this can't be avoided, but for realistic calculations it is extremely unlikely that those boundaries will be relevant.

Because 1/3 in decimal is 0.3333333333333333333333333333
0.3333333333333333333333333333 * 4.5 = 1.4999999999999999999999999998
If you rearranged it like this:
(1.0 * 4.5) / 3

then you would get 1.5 as the answer. Likewise if you left out the redundant 1.0 you would get 1.5.

Ah yes. Of course. I see. There cannot be any guarantee that division rounding errors will not occur. So it will always be important to be aware that regardless of the data type, division rounding errors can occur and how those errors can be dealt with.

In your second paragraph you wrote "... decimal is actually better than double when it comes to rounding errors...". That is not true. The decimal type doesn't always "fix" rounding errors.
Imagine you have two siblings, and the three of you inherit €10,000 in equal amounts. How much will you each get? €3,333.33. There is one cent left over. Who gets that? This problem also exists in the decimal type. It can represent numbers only up to a limited number of decimal places (called the scale).
In C#, when you divide 1m/3m, it stores the result using a certain fixed number of decimal places. It is not, and cannot be, an exact result. Other languages, such as Java, don't allow you to do decimal division of 1/3 without specifying the scale of the result, which is a good thing because it makes you aware of the precision problem.
The decimal type is useful for financial calculations because it stores numbers to a certain number of decimal places, which is the same way that banks store your account balance and transaction amounts, or how shops deal with discounts. For example, if you go to a shop that has a sale on, with 1/3 off everything, and you buy something for €10, you will pay either €6.66 or €6.67, depending on its terms & conditions, but it will certainly not be €6.6666666.... The decimal type will represent either €6.66 or €6.67 with exact precision.

Yes. Thank you. You are right. I have indeed overlooked the division rounding behavior too naively. No matter the internal representation (either binary in case of double or decimal in case of decimal) there are always chances that certain endless digit group repetitions behind the decimal sign will be truncated at a certain point, resulting in rounding errors.
